# Android Geofences (Location Services) - How to trigger in-app events

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-geofence

I've been using the Google Location Services API with Geofences. I can successfully catch Geofence transitions and I receive notifications when I enter and exit Geofences. However, I do not know how to make a Geofence transition make GUI and Data changes to the app.

For an example, if the app is open, I want a small toast to appear. I also need my app to generate a new geofence and discard the old one (but so far I'm only using a set of hardcoded geofences).

But so far, I do not understand how I can interact with my app from the GeofenceTransitionsEventService.java (which is where I "catch" the intents and create the notifications).

Below is my code (now edited, but still not working):

**GPS Activity**

```
public class GPSActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private String mLastUpdateTime;
    private TextView mLatitudeTextView;
    private TextView mLongitudeTextView;
    private final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private boolean locationPermissionGoodToGo = false;
    public double latitude, longitude = 50;

    protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    /**
     * The list of geofences used in this sample.
     */
    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;

    /**
     * Used to keep track of whether geofences were added.
     */
    private boolean mGeofencesAdded;

    /**
     * Used when requesting to add or remove geofences.
     */
    private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;

    /**
     * Used to persist application state about whether geofences were added.
     */
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    // Buttons for kicking off the process of adding or removing geofences.
    private Button mAddGeofencesButton;
    private Button mRemoveGeofencesButton;

    protected ResultReceiver mResultReceiver;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

        mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.latitude_textview));
        mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.longitude_textview));

        // Get the UI widgets.
        mAddGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_geofences_button);
        mRemoveGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_geofences_button);

        // Empty list for storing geofences.
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

        // Initially set the PendingIntent used in addGeofences() and removeGeofences() to null.
        mGeofencePendingIntent = null;

        // Retrieve an instance of the SharedPreferences object.
        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME,
                MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Get the value of mGeofencesAdded from SharedPreferences. Set to false as a default.
        mGeofencesAdded = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, false);
        setButtonsEnabledState();

        // Get the geofences used. Geofence data is hard coded in this sample.
        populateGeofenceList();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        initReceiver();
    }

    public void initReceiver(){
        mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
                // Check result code and/or resultData and take necessary action
                if(resultCode == 0){
                    makeToast(resultData.getString("FROM_GEOFENCE_KEY"));
                    mRemoveGeofencesButton.setText("Remove TESTT");
                }
            }
        };
       // if(mResultReceiver != null){
         //   mAddGeofencesButton.setText("Add Geofences NOT NULL TEST");
        //}
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
    }

    public void makeToast(String string){
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        // setCoordinates();
        else{
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
       // Toast.makeText(this, "Updated: " + mLastUpdateTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    locationPermissionGoodToGo = true;
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
                    //setCoordinates();
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    locationPermissionGoodToGo = false;
                }
                return;
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    public void startGame(){
        //mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
        Geofence fence = new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this geofence.
                .setRequestId("hej")
                .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, 150) //radius in meters
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build();//;
    }

    /**
     * Builds and returns a GeofencingRequest. Specifies the list of geofences to be monitored.
     * Also specifies how the geofence notifications are initially triggered.
     */
    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();

        // The INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER flag indicates that geofencing service should trigger a
        // GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification when the geofence is added and if the device
        // is already inside that geofence.
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);

        // Add the geofences to be monitored by geofencing service.
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);

        // Return a GeofencingRequest.
        return builder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Adds geofences, which sets alerts to be notified when the device enters or exits one of the
     * specified geofences. Handles the success or failure results returned by addGeofences().
     */
    public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    // The GeofenceRequest object.
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    // A pending intent that that is reused when calling removeGeofences(). This
                    // pending intent is used to generate an intent when a matched geofence
                    // transition is observed.
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
            logSecurityException(securityException);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes geofences, which stops further notifications when the device enters or exits
     * previously registered geofences.
     */
    public void removeGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            // Remove geofences.
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    // This is the same pending intent that was used in addGeofences().
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
            logSecurityException(securityException);
        }
    }

    private void logSecurityException(SecurityException securityException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid location permission. " +
                "You need to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION with geofences", securityException);
    }

    /**
     * Runs when the result of calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences() becomes available.
     * Either method can complete successfully or with an error.
     *
     * Since this activity implements the {@link ResultCallback} interface, we are required to
     * define this method.
     *
     * @param status The Status returned through a PendingIntent when addGeofences() or
     *               removeGeofences() get called.
     */
    public void onResult(Status status) {
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            // Update state and save in shared preferences.
            mGeofencesAdded = !mGeofencesAdded;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, mGeofencesAdded);
            editor.apply();

            // Update the UI. Adding geofences enables the Remove Geofences button, and removing
            // geofences enables the Add Geofences button.
            setButtonsEnabledState();

            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    getString(mGeofencesAdded ? R.string.geofences_added :
                            R.string.geofences_removed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        } else {
            // Get the status code for the error and log it using a user-friendly message.
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    status.getStatusCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets a PendingIntent to send with the request to add or remove Geofences. Location Services
     * issues the Intent inside this PendingIntent whenever a geofence transition occurs for the
     * current list of geofences.
     *
     * @return A PendingIntent for the IntentService that handles geofence transitions.
     */
    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
        if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
//DESTROYS EVERYTHING--->        intent.putExtra("RECEIVER_KEY", mResultReceiver);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling
        // addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    /**
     * This sample hard codes geofence data. A real app might dynamically create geofences based on
     * the user's location.
     */
    public void populateGeofenceList() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {

            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                    // geofence.
                    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

                    // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            entry.getValue().latitude,
                            entry.getValue().longitude,
                            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )

                    // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                    // removed after this period of time.
                    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)

                    // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                    // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                    // Create the geofence.
                    .build());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ensures that only one button is enabled at any time. The Add Geofences button is enabled
     * if the user hasn't yet added geofences. The Remove Geofences button is enabled if the
     * user has added geofences.
     */
    private void setButtonsEnabledState() {
        if (mGeofencesAdded) {
            mAddGeofencesButton.setEnabled(false);
            mRemoveGeofencesButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mAddGeofencesButton.setEnabled(true);
            mRemoveGeofencesButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

}
```

**GeofenceTransisitionsIntentService**

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";
    private ResultReceiver mResultReceiver;

    /**
     * This constructor is required, and calls the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with the name for a worker thread.
     */
    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Intent i = getIntent();
    }

    /**
     * Handles incoming intents.
     * @param intent sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided to Location
     *               Services (inside a PendingIntent) when addGeofences() is called.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        mResultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );

            // Send notification and log the transition details.
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            sendToActivity("Sending to activity test");
            //Toast.makeText(this, geofenceTransitionDetails, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, "R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets transition details and returns them as a formatted string.
     *
     * @param context               The app context.
     * @param geofenceTransition    The ID of the geofence transition.
     * @param triggeringGeofences   The geofence(s) triggered.
     * @return                      The transition details formatted as String.
     */
    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
            Context context,
            int geofenceTransition,
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

        // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
        ArrayList triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ",  triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }

    /**
     * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
     * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the MainActivity.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPSActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(GPSActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
                // to decode the Bitmap.
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    /**
     * Maps geofence transition types to their human-readable equivalents.
     *
     * @param transitionType    A transition type constant defined in Geofence
     * @return                  A String indicating the type of transition
     */
    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
            default:
                return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
        }
    }

    public void sendToActivity(String string){
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putString("FROM_GEOFENCE_KEY", string);
        mResultReceiver.send(0, b);
    }
}
```

**Here is my current error message which causes the app to crash**

```
    04-11 17:21:21.952 9528-9528/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction-1/lib/arm
    04-11 17:21:21.974 9528-9528/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
    04-11 17:21:21.974 9528-9528/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
    04-11 17:21:21.983 9528-9528/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
    04-11 17:21:21.984 9528-9528/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
    04-11 17:21:22.008 9528-9528/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction I/InstantRun: Starting server socket listening for package blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction on android.net.LocalSocketAddress@e9aec24
    04-11 17:21:22.010 9528-9528/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction I/InstantRun: Started server for package blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction
    04-11 17:21:22.012 9528-9567/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
    04-11 17:21:22.138 9528-9572/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    04-11 17:21:22.196 9528-9572/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
    04-11 17:21:22.199 9528-9572/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    04-11 17:21:23.868 9528-9572/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb40e3280 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9f7bf6f0
    04-11 17:21:29.767 9528-9572/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction V/RenderScript: 0xaeca2000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
    04-11 17:21:29.793 9528-9769/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GeofenceTransitionsIS]
                                                                                         Process: blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction, PID: 9528
                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.ResultReceiver.send(int, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.sendToActivity(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java:187)
                                                                                             at blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.onHandleIntent(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java:87)
                                                                                             at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                             at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    04-11 17:21:29.898 9528-9572/blueinteraction.mamn01blueinteraction D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9eee6280 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9f7bf670
```

I think these are the only classes I need to show you here for you to be able to help. Otherwise tell me what else to include.

Comment: You need to use a `ResultReceiver` in your `Activity` or `Fragment`

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo Thanks for the reply! Can you elaborate a little more on what exactly this means? I already have the GeofencesTransitionsIntentService successfully detect Geofence Transitions (and this code and setup of classes was bascially just taken from Googles own tutorials and example code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ResultReceiver` to send data back to `Activity` or `Fragment`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html

its `send` method would allow to add `resultCode` and `Bundle` to send data back to class which implemented the receiver.

From your `Activity` or `Fragment`, you will pass an instance of `receiver` to the `IntentService`. Such as,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, receiver);
    activity.startService(intent);
```

Now in your `IntentService` class, you would get the receiver via bungle arguments and keep an instance in the class.

In your `IntentService`'s `onHandleIntent` method, probably any where else you want to trigger the event, you will use the receiver to send the data back to the calling class. Something like this,

```
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ResultReceiver resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);
}
```

`ResultReceiver` is Generic interface for receiving a callback result from someone. Use this by creating a subclass and implement onReceiveResult(int, Bundle), which you can then pass to others and send through IPC, and receive results they supply with send(int, Bundle).

So extend that class and create a new class in your app like this,

```
public abstract class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }
}
```

Then `AddressResultReceiver` might look something like this in your `Activity`,

```
protected AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        // Check result code and/or resultData and take necessary action
        }
    };
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I will try this. It appears I have to make my object either serializable or parcelable to be able to send it. One quick question: Where inside my GeofenceTransitionsIntentService-class should I receive the Receiver? Inside the onHandleIntent-method?

Comment: Actually it implements `Parcelable` already. I have added more code and explanation in the answer

Comment: @AdrianHansson Yes. You can receive the receiver in the `onHandleIntent` method. I have added code for that in the answer too. Check that out!

Comment: So far I'm only getting this error message: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.ResultReceiver.send(int, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object" The object is not null before I send it as a parcel, I checked. What could be wrong? Should I update me code above to the most recent?

Comment: Yes. Please update the code. It's hard to tell anything without looking at it

Comment: I have now updated my my post with the current code (which causes the above mentioned error)

Comment: @AdrianHansson Please copy full stack trace from logcat including line numbers, so that it provide better idea where to look for potential problem.